# Need explanations about a code relative to MPU6050

Tags: arduino-uno

Can anybody please explain me these code. I don't understand how I2C protocol is working.

```
 #include<Wire.h>
  const int MPU=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
  int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;  //int16_t is a 16bit integer. uint16_t is an unsigned 16bit integer

void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)     
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
  Serial.print("AcX = "); Serial.print(AcX);
  Serial.print(" | AcY = "); Serial.print(AcY);
  Serial.print(" | AcZ = "); Serial.print(AcZ);
  Serial.print(" | Tmp = "); Serial.print(Tmp/340.00+36.53);  //equation for temperature in degrees C from datasheet
  Serial.print(" | GyX = "); Serial.print(GyX);
  Serial.print(" | GyY = "); Serial.print(GyY);
  Serial.print(" | GyZ = "); Serial.println(GyZ);
  delay(333);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code opens a I2C connection to the device, transmits an address to read from, and then reads 14 bytes from the device, reassemblying them back into 7 16 bit integers.

I would recommend reading [the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire).

Comment: Wire.write(0x6B); 
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);

plz explain me these three line that what are they doing and how these function works on bot slave and master from both sides 
 
and thansk in advance for helping me

Comment: AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); 

plz explain me these also i read the documentation but didnt understand well that how Wire.read is getting data from exact x axis data adress from MPU i didnt get that how are they getting data from exact address